# Is it possible to exlude words in the hints in gather in Twilio?

Tags: twilio

Gather in Twilio is constantly mistaking "a" with "hey" can i exclude it in the hints? Tried putting "a" in the hints but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There aren't exclusions in hints.

Are you setting the language/accent you expect from your users in the `<Gather>`? Check all of the languages available here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#languagetags

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: language default is en-US right? so no need to change it. It's still mistaking hey with a. maybe 20% percent recognizes a as a. Is there a chance for twilio to add exlusions to hints? how should one ask for that?

Comment: or maybe something like: either in hints or nothing  or pick from hints

Comment: I believe in this case the model is built for understanding natural speech, in which it is more likely someone is saying "hey" than "a". What are you using it for?

Comment: chess moves: <Gather hints="A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1, A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2, A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3, A4, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4, A5, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5, A6, B6, C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, H6, A7, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7, A8, B8, C8, D8, E8, F8, G8, H8"

Comment: is the asr trained for all uses across twilio or is there a chance to train it for a specific twiml or gather?

Comment: That's a good question. The `<Gather>` speech recognition uses Google's Cloud Speech API trained on regular conversation over the phone (at 8khz). If you want to train your own engine, you might be interested in [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot) which allows you to create named fields for detection.